# Streaming Webcam with VLC in C#

Tags: c#, video-streaming, vlc, rtsp, libvlc

I'm currently doing an school project where I have to start a stream of my webcam using VLC in C#.
The main problem I am facing is that i think the codec (the media options) are wrong.
Everytime i try to view my Stream in VLC i get an error or a just a blackscreen without any audio.

Code:

```
public void StartStream()
    {

        var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

        var libDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));

        using (var mediaPlayer = new VlcMediaPlayer(libDirectory))
        {
            var mediaOptions = new[]
            {
                ":sout =#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=Auto,acodec=s16l,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}",
                ":rtp{sdp=rtsp:" + _ip + ":8554/live.sdp}",
                ":no-sout-all",
                ":sout-keep"
            };

            //_ip = Local IPv4 Address 

            mediaPlayer.SetMedia(new Uri(@"dshow://"), mediaOptions);

            mediaPlayer.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Streaming on rtsp://" + _ip + ":8554/live");
        }
    }
```

Kind regards,

Marko

Comment: `":rtp{sdp=rtsp:"` - isn't this missing `//`? So I mean it _should_ be `":rtp{sdp=rtsp://"`?

Comment: You‘re right i was missing that. But it still gives me an error when i try to open my stream

Comment: What error is it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was getting the "vlc main error connection failed connection refused by peer" error or just a plain blackscreen. I tried to disable/enable my firewall but that also didnt work. The error always appears when I try to add a codec to the mediaoptions otherwise it will show me a blackscreen with no sound.